# SPEL - Pound Sign in Expression

Tags: spring, spring-el

I have a pound sign in a string (hex color code) that I do not want the parser to attempt to evaluate:

```
#542582
```

Is there a way to either escape these, or better yet, configure the parser to somehow ignore based on a pattern that matches this?

Comment: Is this a string constant? If yes, just enclose it in quotes.

Comment: Yes. So anything in quotes is not evaluated?

Comment: Single quote, yes `'`; it's considered a literal string.