# Spring Batch EL expression - can't escape # sign

Tags: spring, spring-el

I am using Spring Batch 2.1.9 and have a requirement to write a file name with some text and the run date delimited by a # sign. Unfortunately I can't find a way to display a # sign without breaking the expression. I have tried the following formats, all to no avail:

```
File##{jobParameters[rundate]}

File#{'#' + jobParameters[rundate]}

File${'#'}#{jobParameters[rundate]}

File#{'#'}#{jobParameters[rundate]}
```

Anytime that extra pound sign is included, the rest of the expression fails to display anything. Is there an obscure way to escape a pound sign?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25265098/spel-pound-sign-in-expression

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use String.format("%s#%s",file,rundate) as SPEL?